# jQuery $.extend() - how to not add new members to the first object if they don't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I just stumbled over a small problem when extending javascript objects using jQuery. When executing

```
var item = $.extend(options.itemDefaults, item);
```

`options.itemDefaults` is extended with the properties that are already in `item` and the result is passed to `item`. So far, so good.

But the *next* time this line is executed, `options.itemDefaults` has all the property values that `item` had, instead of the original defaults. My defaults are lost!

I realize I could simply store the defaults object in a temporary variable, and extend the temporary variable instead, but it seems a bit lengthy. Is there a way to do what I'm after (overriding default values with supplied ones, taking defaults when no values are supplied, but not changing the default object) without that detour?

**Update:** It seems this wasn't as easy to get around as I hoped. When I do

```
var defaults = options.itemDefaults;
var $item = $.extend(defaults, { attributeModel: options.attributeModel }, item);
defaults = undefined
```

in each iteration, I *still* add properties from `item` on `options.itemDefaults`! How do I get around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try,

```
var item = $.extend(true, {}, options.itemDefaults, item);
```

The [`true`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) flag indicates that a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/122704#122704) must be made.

We use an empty object `{}` as the target so the defaults are not tampered with.

Properties of `options.itemDefaults`, and `item` will be copied into the empty object.

Comment: Brilliant! This was exactly was I was after. Thanks! =)